# Fetch a value from a response and write into a file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm new to groovy in soapui. I am trying to fetch a value from a mockservice response tag and store that in a text file. Then another service will read that file to use in a request.

//Response tag from a mockresponse of a service i.e. service1
<ref:ReferState RequestID = "0004350758">

//store in a file so that the request from another service can use this ID

//Request from another service i.e. service2
<ref:ReferState RequestID = "0004350758">

And this Request ID value is incrementing every run.

Can someone help please with the groovy code? many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using a Property Transfer test step, getting the value via a regex from the response and storing it in a test suite or project property.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your feedback. I thought of that using a property transfer too, but the problem I have is that the response value that I need to extract is from a different project. So im trying to figure out a way to chain that data between 2 different projects.

Comment: Ok, I'll write up an answer for you in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up a Groovy Test Step to run after your service call (assuming it's SOAP).

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)

//getting response value with xpath, this you will have to figure out yourself depending on the XML structure:
def responseValue = xml.getNodeValue("//*:ReferState/*: RequestID") 
log.info "responseValue : ${responseValue}"

def outFile = new File("/your/path/and/filename.txt")
outFile.write(responseValue)
```

And then in the other project, you can access the value as:

```
def inputValue = new File("/your/path/and/filename.txt").text
log.info "inputValue : ${inputValue}"
```

If you want to use that value in a new service call, put it in a property:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("RequestID", "responseValue")
```

and in your next request parameterise it:

```
<soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:SomeRequest>
             <ref:RequestID>${#TestCase#responseValue}</ns:address>
             ...
```

---

Coincidentally, SoapUI also has global propeties that are visible across projects:

Setting:

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("GlobalPropName", "PropValue")
```

Getting

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("GlobalPropName") == "PropValue"
```

Comment: Hi there again, thank you so much for that. Appreciate a lot your help. I'm going to try this solution now. I was also wondering, instead of outputting the response value from the response to a file, is it possible to set it straight away as global property then the request in another project can fetch that value from the global property? If it is, can you show me how also please? thanks so much again..

Comment: hi, I tried these commands above, but the responseValue is null 
<p>```groovy
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)</p>

<p>//getting response value with xpath 
def responseValue = xml.getNodeValue("//*:ReferState/*: RequestID") 
log.info "responseValue : ${responseValue}"</p>
<p>//then I set the responseValue as global property
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("GlobalPropName", responseValue)```</p>

but the result is null. its not getting the value from the response, any idea? thanks so much again

Comment: Hi again, I've solved the problem now with the xpath with this

```groovy def responseValue = xml.getNodeValue("//@RequestID")
```

Thanks again for your help.